# Jump to a element automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, html

i have elements like this on page

```
<a href="#hi">go to hi</a>
.
.
<a name="hi">hi text here</a>
```

but i would like users go to "hi text here" at first on page loading. how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest that you first test for another hash before moving your users' browser to focus another element:

```
if (!document.location.hash){
    document.location.hash = 'hi';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y4ADd/).

Incidentally, you can use the hash (the part after the `#` in the URL) to jump to any element that has an `id`, you don't need to use the named-anchors (`<a name="hi">...</a>`).

Comment: what about when i must jump to elemet with a class?

Comment: Then it starts to get a little fuzzier; because you can have multiple elements with the same class-name. Somehow you'd have to define which of the multiple elements you need to jump to. I'd suggest asking a separate question to address this need.

Answer (score 5):

Either, you can use the URL with the anchor (mysite.com/#hi) or you could use javascript:

```
document.getElementById('hi').scrollIntoView(true);
```

Please note that you should use ID, not name.

Answer (score 2):

i think it would be usefull to work with anchors:

```
<a name="hi">here goes the text information what you like</a>
```

Create a link to the "hi Section" inside the same document:

```
<a href="#hi">Go to hi</a>
```

Or, create a link to the "hi Section" from another page:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/html_links.htm#hi">
Visit the hi Section</a>
```

Comment: this Jump to a element automatically "on page load" ? i say no

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery along with its scrollTo plugin, and then write something like this:

```
$.scrollTo("a[name = hi]");
```

It should work just fine.

Comment: +1, still relevant to the question.  User didn't get a preferred way to achieve his goals, he just asked for options.