# How to load a page starting at a specific section ID, using template.render() using python, jinja2

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

**Here's the python code:**

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

**However, I'd like to load index.html starting at the anchor tag below:**

(wherein this anchor tag is in the index.html file)

```
<section> id="home">
```

**How would i change the python code to do this?**

As you can tell, I'm new, and currently working through the Google App Engine tutorials.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are a bit confused. With jinja2 and Python code all you can achieve is to produce the page server-side. If you want to jump into a specific section within that page you should do that client-side by using JavaScript ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696691/8418)).

Comment: Or alternately create the link with the hash in the first place and use a JavaScript fallback to set it if the page is loaded without one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's supose you want acces your page at /yourpage and on home section. You could do this with a redirect:

```
YourHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect("/yourpage#home")
```

So you need to put the section id just after the "#" sign.

It worked for me at least on Google Chrome.

Comment: Even though it is possible with this _hack_ I believe it should be done using client side code for sanity :)